# Using Coral Dev Board as wifi router

Tags: google-coral, nmcli

Im doing a project with IP cameras and Coral, so I'd like to know is it possible to create a wifi hotspot using only coral. I've tried couple ways, but they ended up to be not working

Comment: Hello @MrFlorius,
You need to explain your problem much more detailed. For instance, what kind of ways did you try? It will help others to help you much faster.

Comment: You mean your coral as a hotspot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coral Dev board uses "Murata LBEE5U91CQ module". And this chip does support dual mode network topology (AP + STA). Please see the details at : https://wireless.murata.com/type-1cq.html.

Driver is nl80211 and AP is supported so standard Linux tools can be used. Generally this is accomplished with hostapd, you can see an example configuration here: https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/. That being said, hostapd lets you configure many more modes that will enable. The maximum data rate will vary wildly based on your configuration, but the device can support 802.11n with two antennas so up to 300 Mbps may be possible. Run 'iw list' for more info on capabilities.

Note: both hostapd and iw need to be installed via apt.